# How would I create a never ending level for BGE

Tags: game-engine

How would I make a city or terrain in the BGE so that when a player gets close to the edge it will generate more of whatever I tell it to, (mountains, roads, etc... etc...). I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Start by clarifying your idea, since the orda of heater owners of this place attacks you, what you want is a procedural generator in BGE, something difficult but not impossible I have something that works fairly well, but I need work in the part of the code of python if you want to try to help with it I can share it but you need to learn python and learn more about the logical bricks before trying